# Mono Self Closing tags XslCompiledTransform

Tags: c#, xslt, mono

I'm trying to ensure that my XSL transform always produces self closing tags that is:

```
<item attribute="value" />
```

not

```
<item attribute="value"></item>
```

There are a lot of posts on the net of people having trouble trying to get the opposite of what I want.

This seems to work fine on my windows build but I'm running my program in Mono 2.10.8.1 on Wheezy which seems to always produce the second undesirable option.

```
    XmlWriterSettings xmlSettings = new XmlWriterSettings();
    xmlSettings.Indent = true;
    xmlSettings.NewLineChars = "\n";
    xmlSettings.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;

    XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xml));

    using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(outputStream, xmlSettings))
    {
         m_SoapXSLT.Transform(reader, writer);
    }

    string outStr = outputStream.ToString();
```

Does anyone have an idea of why they would be different of if there is something I can do to ensure my desired behavior?

Here are some extracts from the XSL document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
xmlns:xdt="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-datatypes"
xmlns:err="http://www.w3.org/2005/xqt-errors"
exclude-result-prefixes="xs xdt err fn">

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"  omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

...
<xsl:if test="self::node()[@type='46']">
    <xsl:element name="elementName">
        <xsl:attribute name="NumItems">
            <xsl:value-of select="count(self::node()/selections/selection)"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:for-each select="self::node()/items/item">
                <xsl:element name="item">
                    <xsl:attribute name="A">
                        <xsl:value-of select="@data1"/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="B">
                        <xsl:value-of select="@data2"/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="Num">
                        <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:if>
...
```

Comment: neither of the things shown is valid xml... but if they were: they would be *essentially* identical; but; how are you doing this currently? i.e. in the xslt, what does your "item" markup look like?

Comment: Well `attribute=value` is not even following XML rules so I doubt you get that format with unquoted attribute values. As for serializing empty elements, it is up to the serializer how to do that. If you want to enforce a certain format then write your own serializer (i.e. own XmlWriter) doing what you want.

Comment: Please excuse my hand written XML it was just an example they idea was just to point out the how the element is closed. I will add an example of how the XSL is written in a few minutes. I know they are both valid XML (after my correction) but the document is very large and the full closing tags are adding additional bulk to the final document. Please note most of the elements contain only attributes.

Comment: As I said, you need to implement your desired serialization behaviour by implementing your own XmlWriter, that can be done extending an existing implementation. As for your XSLT code and avoiding bulk, I would use literal result elements in the form `<item A="{@data1}" B="{@data2}" Num="{position()}"/>` instead of using `xsl:element` and `xsl:attribute`, as those are only needed if you need to compute a node name based on input values. But of course that will only shorten the XSLT, the result tree serialization is not determined by that.

Comment: Of course I am only interested in the bulk in the final document not the XSLT. I've not looking into overriding components of the XmlWriter I'll look into that and see if it can help me get the desired behavior unless anyone else has other suggestions?

Comment: After coming back to this a while later I've tried to implement my own XmlWriter but I've not been able to make any progress. I've used the instructions here http://www.tkachenko.com/blog/archives/000585.html to make a base template class but I'm not sure how to change WriteEndElement to not write the full tag. Anyone know how I can proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason my windows build was creating self closing tags was that it was using the System.XML.dll from the .Net framework v2.0.50727 while Mono was using a different version that leaned more towards creating full end tags.

To get the desired behavior I had to copy the following two dlls from my .net framework to the local directory of my executable:

System.XML.dll and System.Data.SqlXml.dll

Please note I had to rename System.**XML**.dll to System.**Xml**.dll for Mono to pick up and accept the dll.

Once this was done my Xml output was the same as my windows implementation.